# Getting error when validation error in “422 (Unprocessable Entity)” Laravel7

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation, laravel-7

I am using laravel 7 . Whhen I input all data succefully added to database. But if any field empty then error will be come "“422 (Unprocessable Entity)” Laravel7"

If any laravel validation error comes then i want to show into the respective field error .
But i am not getting value in the

```
error: function (data) {
   console.log("data");
      console.log('Error:', data);
      $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
}
```

Below is my coding Section

```
  if ($("#productForm").length > 0) {
            $("#productForm").validate({
  
                submitHandler: function(form)
                 {
  
                      var actionType = $('#btn-save').val();
                      $('#btn-save').html('Sending..');
                       
                     $.ajax({
                              data: $('#productForm').serialize(),
                              
                              url:"contact-list/store",
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: 'json',
                              success: function (data) {
                                console.log("dgfd");
                              $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
                              $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                              $('#ajax-product-modal').modal('hide');
                              $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
                              var oTable = $('#laravel_datatable').dataTable();
                              oTable.fnDraw(false);
               
                              },
                              error: function (data) {
                                console.log("data");
                                  console.log('Error:', data);
                                  $('#btn-save').html('Save Changes');
                              }
                            });
                    }
            })
        }
```

My controller :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validate = $request->validate([
                        'name' => 'required',
                        'email' => 'email',
                        'phone' => 'digits:10',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'country' => 'required',
                        'state' => 'required',
                        // 'comment' => 'required',
                        'organization' => 'required',
                        'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
                    ],
                    [
                        'captcha.captcha' => 'Incorrect Captcha'
                    ]
                );

        // if ($validate->fails())
        // {
        //     return response()->json(['errors'=>$validate->errors()->all()]);
        // }

        $id=$request->contact_id;

        $customer = CustomerContact::find($id);
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->phone = $request->phone;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->country_id = $request->country;
        $customer->state_id = $request->state;
        $customer->comment = $request->comment;
        $customer->organization = $request->organization;
        $customer->captcha = $request->captcha;

 
        $a=$customer->update();
        return Response::json($a);

    }

Nd modal 
 
    <div class="modal fade" id="ajax-product-modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="productCrudModal"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        
        <form id="productForm" name="productForm" class="form-horizontal">
           
            @csrf
             <div class="form-header">
                <h4>Edit Employee Information</h4>
             </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required">Your Name</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" id="contact_id">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                    <span class="error_message"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email Id</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                    <span class="error_message"></span>
            </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

I am not getting how to show error in modal structure.  Help me in this if anyone have idea.

Comment: ajax validation will help you to do it https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-ajax-form-validation-with-laravel-58example.html

Comment: There are a lot of way to check validation on front-end, html has a `required` attribute  to do that : `<input type="text" name="name" required>`

Answer (score 0):

try uncomment this :

```
// if ($validate->fails())
    // {
    //     return response()->json(['errors'=>$validate->errors()->all()]);
    // }
```

this code returns the errors as json and let you easily print them

and in jquery try logging the data.response because the error returns with many objects like status code and other stuff

Comment: Actually i wa used that also but getting same issue.

Comment: try this  :

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}